# can you open cinema 4d files in blender?

Tags: modeling

i got a cinema 4d file by accident not seeing that there were no other models types available and now i need a way to open it in blender. it would be ideal not to use cinema 4d but if i have to the i have to i guess. any help?

Comment: No, you can't open C4D files in Blender, you need to use C4D to export the model as Obj or FBX or so

Comment: maybe download a trial version of C4D open and export.